# Unlabeled exception in threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a chunk of code like this

```
def f(x):
    try:
       g(x)
    except Exception, e:
       print "Exception %s: %d" % (x, e)

def h(x):
    thread.start_new_thread(f, (x,))
```

Once in a while, I get this:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

Unlike the code sample, that's the complete text.  I assume after the "by" there's supposed to be a thread ID and after the colon there are supposed to be stack traces, but nope, nothing.  I don't know how to even start to debug this.

Comment: @alexD -- Sadly, no.  The actual g function is a call to a website that might very well cause a real exception.  It seems to happen at random.  Happens pretty often though.

Comment: It does say it's an unhandled exception.  So it's unlikely coming from the `g()` function.  Maybe it's coming from the thread creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're seeing means the interpreter was exiting (because the main thread exited) while another thread was still executing Python code. Python will clean up its environment, cleaning out and throwing away all of the loaded modules (to make sure as many finalizers as possible execute) but unfortunately that means the still-running thread will start raising exceptions when it tries to use something that was already destroyed. And then that exception propagates up to the `start_new_thread` function that started the thread, and it will try to report the exception -- only to find that what it tries to use to report the exception is also gone, which causes the confusing empty error messages.

In your specific example, this is all caused by your thread being started *and your main thread exiting right away*. Whether the newly started thread gets a chance to run before, during or after the interpreter exits (and thus whether you see it run as normal, run partially and report an error or never see it run) is entirely up to the OS thread scheduler.

If you're using threads (which is not a bad thing to avoid) you probably want to not have threads running while you're exiting the interpreter. The `threading.Thread` class is a better interface for starting new threads, and it will make the interpreter wait for all threads by default, on exit. If you *really* don't want to wait for a thread to end, you can set its 'daemonic' flag in the Thread object to get the old behaviour -- including the problem you see here.

Comment: That makes sense.  Was it in the docs somewhere or did you just know that?

Comment: It's not in the docs as such, no, although the individual bits are. Unfortunately threads are sufficiently complex that there are a large number of things you need to either know or infer from how things work. I've been using Python and threads (separately and together) for a long time and I *know* I don't know everything yet -- which is why I recommend not using threads :)

Comment: Yes, I managed to bring down my company's mail sender yesterday with them (not with this error but with making a rookie mistake confusing lexical binding with early binding then making the same mistake *again*.)